Django migrations: SeparateDatabaseAndState vs --fake
Let's say I have a model:
class MyModel(models.Model):
  ...
  field_no_need_anymore = Charfield(...)

I want to remove field_no_need_anymore, but I don't want to apply changes to the database immediately - I will drop this column manually later (next day or day after). In Django for this case I have two options:
python manage.py migrate --fake

or add this to the migration:
operations = [
  migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
    state_operations=[
      migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='mymodel',
        name='field_no_need_anymore',
      )
    ],
    database_operations=[]
  )
]

In both cases there will be a new record in django_migrations table, while no changes to the target table will be applied. So, when you use --fake and when SeparateDatabaseAndState?
